# Passing a model into RedirectToAction()

Tags: asp.net-mvc, redirecttoaction

I'm curious how this works.  In MVC you can call View() and pass a model as a parameter, but RedirectToAction (one of its incarnations at least) takes a 'routeValues' object, which appears to be the closest match.

If your model is passed in this parameter will that model type be available in the subsequent action method?  Or are there caveats involved that might prevent accurate translation in some circumstances?

Comment: Are you talking about an actual _model_ or a _model_ _object_?

Comment: @OakNinja-- I'm not 100% what the difference is between the two you're referring to?  When I say 'model' I mean the object tagged as `@model` in Razor that's available to a View and passed to it from the controller.

I know you can use TempData or a ViewBag to stuff a model into temporary storage while redirecting; would anyone know why you can't pass one as a parameter when redirecting?  The View() method has an overload that allows you to...wondering why you can't do the same in a redirect.

Comment: The _object_ passed into a strongly typed view is of type _model_. In effect, the @model line in the view tells the view that it will be passed an object that has the properties of a specific model. Made it clearer? If not, i'll give you a more extensive answer as an answer!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you need to pass in some-what complex objects to an action after a redirect, you probably want to use either a Session or TempData:

From "[What is ASP.NET MVC TempData](http://www.devcurry.com/2012/05/what-is-aspnet-mvc-tempdata.html)"

> ASP.NET MVC TempData dictionary is used to share data between
>   controller actions. The value of TempData persists until it is read or
>   until the current user’s session times out

By default TempData uses a Session to persist the information, however, as with much of MVC, this is an extensibility point, where you can plug in a [Cookie-based provider](http://brockallen.com/2012/06/11/cookie-based-tempdata-provider/) if you prefer.

Comment: Yep, I usually slap the object into the TempData dictionary.  The Action you redirected to should then check TempData to see if it has a model available for it.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot pass a model object in there but you can pass individual properties that will map to a model in the action that you redirect to.

That works by building up the url to redirect to using the properties, and the model binder in the receiving action.

Answer (score 2):

`Redirect...` methods cause client-side-and-back trip, so - no, the model will not be available.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want :

1. Save your model in a Tempdata

   ```
           RequestModel rq = new  RequestModel()   
           ....assign something to your model..
           TempData["request"] = rq;

           return Redirect("RequestAcknowledgement");
   ```
2. Now create an Action Result for the view you are redirecting to and pass your TempData back to a model. Then return the model to a view.

   ```
    public ActionResult RequestAcknowledgement()
       {
          RequestsModel request =  (RequestsModel)TempData["request"];

          return View(request);
       }
   ```