# Dictionary loses value when passed as a parameter?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dictionary

I am using MVC, I populate some values before redirecting to an action, During this my dictionary always has a count of 0?

I check the count before it passes and its over 0 but always 0 when it comes through the other side.

I pass other string values too but they all come through fine.

My Redirect to action.

```
return RedirectToAction(
    "APNewQuote", 
    new { 
        OENumber = "", QuoteNumber = "", ClaimNumber = ClaimNumber,
        MotorBodyRepairer = "", VehicleRegistration = vRegistration,
        vehicleMakeId = "", vehicleModelId = "", vehicleRangeId = "",
        vehicleMakeModels = "", vehicleModelCode = "",
        year = vYear, OEParts = OEParts }
);
```

My Action result receiving the values.

```
public ActionResult APNewQuote(string OENumber, string QuoteNumber, string ClaimNumber,
    string MotorBodyRepairer, string VehicleRegistration, int? vehicleMakeId,
    int? vehicleModelId, int? vehicleRangeId, string vehicleMakeModels,
    string vehicleModelCode, int? year, Dictionary<string,string> OEParts )
```

Could someone please tell me how i can prevent this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing a model into RedirectToAction()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13957041/passing-a-model-into-redirecttoaction)

Comment: Have you heard of view models? They are great...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the dictionary doesn't get serialized. As explained [in this question's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13957041/passing-a-model-into-redirecttoaction) `If you need to pass in some-what complex objects to an action after a redirect, you probably want to use either a Session or TempData:`

So save your dictionary into `TempData` or the `Session` object.

usage:

```
// save
TempData["myDictionary"] = OEParts;


// retrieve
var myDic = TempData["myDictionary"] as Dictionary<string,string>;
```

[HttpContext.Session Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.session.aspx)

[ControllerBase.TempData Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controllerbase.tempdata%28v=vs.118%29.aspx)

Comment: How do i save a dictionary into a TempData

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
    var oem = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        DataTable dt = DataAccessLayer.GetPartsDamaged()
        foreach(DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            oem.Add(row["key"].ToString(),row["value"].ToString());
        }

    return RedirectToAction("APNewQuote", new { OENumber = "", QuoteNumber = "", ClaimNumber = ClaimNumber, MotorBodyRepairer = "", VehicleRegistration = vRegistration, vehicleMakeId = "", vehicleModelId = "", vehicleRangeId = "", vehicleMakeModels = "", vehicleModelCode = "", year = vYear, OEParts = oem});
```

Comment: My dictionary between 1 - 200 key value pairs, would i need to add that for each key value pair?

Comment: From where you're getting 1-200 key value pairs? From db?

Comment: From a PDF for car parts damages

Comment: then insert those values in db and loop through in code and construct dictionary.

Comment: I don;t think all that is necessary for passing a dictionary across a redirect. I think @Csteinmueller has the right idea with TempDate.