# Dictionary loses values when passed as a parameter

Tags: c#, dictionary, parameter-passing

My title question is absolutely the same as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23633084/dictionary-loses-value-when-passed-as-a-parameter)

However that does not answer my question.

```
static void Main() {
    Dictionary<string,int> d=new Dictionary<string,int>();
    d["asu"]=1;
    d["babi"]=1;
    c(d);
    Console.Write(d["asu"]);
    //output=0
}
static void c(Dictionary<string,int> d){
    d["asu"]--;
}
```

The above code decrease a value  in `d` variable inside `Main` method, when it should only decrease value inside `c()` method and should not decrease inside `Main` method too. How do I keep the `Dictionary` in `Main` method so the values not decreased by passed parameter.

Comment: Please remove the [profanity](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22232/are-expletives-cursing-swear-words-or-vulgar-language-allowed-on-se-sites)

Answer (score 5):

`Dictionary` is a reference type. You are not making a copy of the data when you pass it around. You're just passing a reference to the same underlying object.

If you want to modify a copy, you'll need to explicitly make one; try:

```
var copy = d.ToDictionary(t=>t.Key, t=>t.Value);
```

Comment: This is correct. A Dictionary is a reference type. By passing a reference to d to the function c, you give c the power to change your original d. If you don't want this to happen, you must explicitly create a new copy of the dictionary.

Answer (score 3):

Create a dictionary copy before passing into method c

```
c(new Dictionary<string, int>(d));
```

Otherwise, variables point to the same object.